# (C++14) Array of lambdas: error: 'name' declared as array of 'auto'

Tags: c++, arrays, lambda, c++14

I'm having a bad time figuring this error out. I'll admit, I'm new to c++ and my difficulty comes from not understanding the error message.

Here's the code:

```
auto selectionFuncs[8] =
{
    [&](const Vector3& min, const Vector3& max) 
    { 
      return max.x_ == seamValues.x_ || max.y_ == seamValues.y_ || max.z_ == seamValues.z_;
    },

    [&](const Vector3& min, const Vector3& max) 
    { 
      return min.x_ == seamValues.x_; 
    },

    [&](const Vector3& min, const Vector3& max) 
    { 
      return min.z_ == seamValues.z_; 
    },

    [&](const Vector3& min, const Vector3& max) 
    { 
      return min.x_ == seamValues.x_ && min.z_ == seamValues.z_; 
    },

    [&](const Vector3& min, const Vector3& max) 
    { 
      return min.y_ == seamValues.y_; 
    },

    [&](const Vector3& min, const Vector3& max) 
    { 
      return min.x_ == seamValues.x_ && min.y_ == seamValues.y_; 
    },

    [&](const Vector3& min, const Vector3& max) 
    { 
      return min.y_ == seamValues.y_ && min.z_ == seamValues.z_; 
    },

    [&](const Vector3& min, const Vector3& max) 
    { 
      return min.x_ == seamValues.x_ && min.y_ == seamValues.y_ && min.z_ == seamValues.z_; 
    }
};
```

And here's the error:

```
error: ‘selectionFuncs’ declared as array of ‘auto’
```

From googling around, it seems using auto in this instance is not allowed in C++11 but it should be in C++14, however I must be declaring it wrong somehow and can't figure it out.

Help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can't declare an array with `auto`, simple as that. Use an array of `std::function` to store lambdas.

Comment: @DeiDei have any examples I can look at that would be helpful in this situation? Could you go as far as showing the syntax? I will google in the mean time! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Pretty sure the type of each lambda is unrelated to the type of any other lambda (they're all syntactic sugar for creating instances of a unique functor each time a specific lambda is needed), even if they appear superficially the same (prototype etc.), so yeah, a wrapper like `std::function` would be needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C++ language forbids having arrays declared with `auto`. You have two good options: function pointers and even better - `std::function`. Something like this:

```
std::function<bool(const Vector3&, const Vector3&)> selectionFuncs[8] =
{
    [&](const Vector3& min, const Vector3& max) 
    { 
      return max.x_ == seamValues.x_ || max.y_ == seamValues.y_ || max.z_ == seamValues.z_;
    },

    [&](const Vector3& min, const Vector3& max) 
    { 
      return min.x_ == seamValues.x_; 
    },

    // ...
};
```

Don't forget to `#include <functional>`. Then you just use the elements of the array like any other functions.

Comment: I see. I will need to read up on this more to understand everything. I'm curious about why there is a bool type in the template.

Comment: The `bool` is the return type of your encapsulated lambdas.

Comment: Oh! That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your quick help!

Answer (score 5):

If you are only storing the lambdas in the array for code convenience and not for runtime selection, you don't have to store them in an array. A tuple can do the same thing:

```
auto selectionFuncs = std::make_tuple(
    [&](const Vector3& min, const Vector3& max) 
    { 
      return max.x_ == seamValues.x_ || max.y_ == seamValues.y_ || max.z_ == seamValues.z_;
    },
    //...
```

But if you actually want runtime selection, you will have to cast the lambdas to `std::function`s or function pointers (further explained in the other answer), as that's how the C++ type system works with functions and lambdas (Lambdas are distinct types but can be cast to their respective function types if they are stateless).